# python (reverse) Interpolate assign a tenor-point value to two closest tenor point

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am looking to do a reverse type of (numpy) interpolation.

Consider the case where I have a 'risk' value of 2.2, and that is mapped to this tenor-point value of 1.50.
Consider a have a tenor-list of list (or array) = [0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0].
Now, I would like to attribute this risk-value of 2.2 to what it would be, as mapped to the closest two tenor-points (in this case 1.0 and 2.0), in the form of a linear interpolation.

In this example, the function will generate the risk-value of 2.0, (which is mapped to expiry value of 1.50) to

1. for the 1.0 tenor point : of 2.2 * (1.5 - 1.0)/(2.0 - 1.0)
2. for the 2.0 tenor point : of 2.2 * (2.0 - 1.5)/(2.0 - 1.0)

Is there a numpy/scipy/panda or python code that would do this?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like linear to me. Basically values at `1.0` and `2.0` are value at `1.5` divided by `2`.

Comment: hi @QuangHoang, it's the simplest example I could think of... the reality would be something like given (a) array of risk-values [0.422, 1.053, 100.423, -99.53], and (b) mapped to tenor-array of [1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0], how can one assign the risk-value array to a larger tenor-array of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 12.0, 15.0] where the original risk-values are re-allocated to the less-granular grid using linear-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have attempted a bit of a different approach but maybe this helps you. I try to interpolate the points for the new grid points using `interpolate.interp1d` (with the option to extrapolate points `fill_value="extrapolate"`) to extend the range beyond the interval given. In your first example the new points were always internal, in the comment example also external, so I used the more general case. This still might be polished, but should give an idea:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def dist_val(vpt, arr):
    dist = np.abs(arr-np.full_like(arr, vpt))
    i0 = np.argmin(dist)
    dist[i0] = np.max(dist) + 1
    i1 = np.argmin(dist)
    return (i0, i1)

def dstr_lin(ra, tnl, tnh):
    '''returns a risk-array like ra for tnh based on tnl'''
    if len(tnh) < len(tnl) or len(ra) != len(tnl):
        return -1
    rah = []
    for vh in tnh:
        try:
            rah.append((vh, ra[tnl.index(vh)]))
        except ValueError:
            rah.append((vh, float(interpolate.interp1d(tnl, ra, fill_value="extrapolate")(vh))))
    return rah

ra =  [0.422, 1.053, 100.423, -99.53]
tn_low = [1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0]
tn_high = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 12.0, 15.0]

print(dstr_lin(ra, tn_low, tn_high))
```

this results in

```
[(1.0, 0.422), (2.0, 1.053), (3.0, 34.17633333333333), (5.0, 100.423), (7.0, 20.4418), (10.0, -99.53), (12.0, -179.51120000000003), (15.0, -299.483)]
```

Careful though, I am not sure how "well behaved" your data is, interpolation or extrapolation might swing out of range so use with care.